# Rails json find empty field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have some JSON. How can i get only not empty "value" field?  I want to get only `"value": "sun-icon"` and `"value": "terracotta"`

```json
{
    "line_items": [{
        "properties": [{
                "name": "Customization Cost",
                "value": ""
            },
            {
                "name": "Standard Bundle Label 1",
                "value": "sun-icon"
            },
            {
                "name": "Custom Bundle Label 1",
                "value": ""
            },
            {
                "name": "Bundle Color 1",
                "value": "terracotta"
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say something like that

```rb
json = JSON.parse(my_str)

json['line_items'].map{|hsh| hsh['properties'].select{|hsh2| hsh2['value'].empty?}}.flatten.compact
```